# SSRS 2005 Return the parameters that do not return a matching record

Tags: sql-server-2008, reportingservices-2005

I am using SSRS 2005. I have a report that has a single parameter "@Serial". Our support technicians enter computer serial numbers into the parameter field and generate a report returning the matching records from the database table. The count of serial numbers is not hard set and ranges from 1 to 100++.

My ultimate goal is to list the serial numbers that do not return a matching record.

In SSRS I have tried using the =JOIN(Parameters!Serial.Value,",") to list all of the parameter values (serial numbers) into a text field. This works fine to list ALL of the parameters passed but I do not know the correct expression to convert the list so it only contains only the un-matched serial numbers.

It was suggested that I use a Left Join in the SQL query, however, I don't know how to get the parameters entered by the technician into a temp table in SQL so that I can Join the two tables.

Any help on either method is appreciated, and alternatives to these two methods are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

wouldn't you use the CountDistinct control for the parameter values